# change marginLeft and marginRight from a javascript statment using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using Highcharts, how can I only change the chart marginLeft and marginRight and then redraw it from a javascript statement.
I need to re-adjust the chart margin in some places in my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ovh9dwqc/

I tried something like:

```
test = $('#container').highcharts();
test.margin[4] = 50;
test.redraw();
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not supported, but a little hacky way to do it:

```
    //JAVASCRIPT code to change left and right margin
    test = $('#container').highcharts();
    $.each(test.axes, function(i, e) {
       e.isDirty = true; 
    });
    test.margin[1] = 50;
    test.redraw();
```

First: it's margin[1], not margin[4]. Margins are: 0-top, 1-right, 2-bottom, 3-left. Just like in CSS.

Then we need to inform Highcharts that axes needs to be redrawn, so we are setting for all of them `isDirty` flag to true.

We could also use `test.xAxis[0].update()` instead `test.redraw()`. That will force all axes to reflow.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ovh9dwqc/1/