# Set HighCharts marginTop dynamically based on mobile device screen size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, ionic-framework

How do you set [marginTop](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginTop) dynamically based on current window height?

E.g.

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      type: 'solidgauge',
      // set to -50 if window height is 700px...
      // set to -20 if window height is 500px...
      marginTop: -50
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547500/change-marginleft-and-marginright-from-a-javascript-statment-using-highcharts) might help

Comment: Set a variable outside of the chart config based on whatever logic that you want, then use that variable as your marginTop value.

Comment: @jlbriggs - thanks. This is what I did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
function ChartController($scope, $window) {
  $scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        // set to -50 if window height is 700px...
        // set to -20 if window height is 500px...
        marginTop: 0
      }
    }
  }

  if ($window.innerHeight >= 568 && $window.innerHeight <= 639) {
    $scope.chartConfig.options.chart.marginTop = -95;
  }
}
```